# Why this query is so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

This query appears in mysql slow query log: it takes 11 seconds.

```
INSERT INTO record_visits
( record_id, visit_day )
VALUES
( '567', NOW() );
```

The table has 501043 records and it's structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `record_visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visit_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `visit_cnt` bigint(20) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `record_id_visit_day` (`record_id`,`visit_day`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

What could be wrong? Why this INSERT takes so long?

## UPDATE

I found out, what was the cause of all the troubles. There were a very heavy "ON INSERT" trigger created on that table. Together with MyISAM table locking, it gave enormous query times for the INSERT query. Probably this is why @Oswald in the comments could not reproduce this situation.

Real problem here is that MySQL does not log queries inside of triggers and you always have to remember about them when profiling your application.

Thank you for your help, everyone, accepting answer that was closes to the solution.

Comment: Does restarting the MySQL Server help?

Comment: Probably because of your UNIQUE index. But it should not be THAT slow.

Comment: @Time Machine no, it's still the same after restart.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. 0.0004 seconds on my Centrino Duo 1.66GHz with 2.5GB RAM and 890796 rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's not the query itself that is slow, but you're running other queries on the server that is locking the table.  MyISAM uses table level locking, so a query that needs a given table will lock all other queries that need that table even if they touch different rows.  For example, if you often have long-running SELECT queries, your INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries won't be able to execute until all selects that were running when you issued the query complete.

If you say SHOW PROCESSLIST from another prompt while your insert is running you'll probably see that it's in the "Locked" state.   If it turns out to be another state, and there are no long-running selects blocking it, you should post that because that will help narrow down the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you try adding a data to this table, mysql checks all **record_id_visit_day** rows because of UNIQUE index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL, but does a UNIQUE KEY implies that there is an index on the visit_day column? If not, try creating one.

Comment: UNIQUE KEY means that there is a 2 column index on columns `record_id` and`visit_day`. As far as I know, adding indexes only slows the inserts and updates down, how will this help?

Comment: A unique key has to be checked every time an insert is to be made. So if you have a unique key but no index, every index results in a sequential scan over the key columns to ensure there is no duplicate value.

Comment: I read the unique declaration wrong, but i assume you need an combined index on both keys.

Comment: I just learned that MySQL already has created this index for you by specifying the UNIQUE contraint. Is your query still slow if you remove the unique contraint?